# configure rolling OR delete after X time of data dir , to prevent “out of space” error

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I configured the cluster to claim 5g for the data dir

```
   volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: elasticsearch-data
          spec:
            accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 5Gi
```

I like to configure the cluster to roll data for example after it Reaches 4g
or another method that elastic search is using, the main point is that i don't want it to throw
"out of space" error when data is Reaches to 5g

Comment: perhaps you can configure ilm for each index to remove old data. It may not be wise to delete data form elasticsearch's data directory.

Comment: where how ? what is the best practice ?

Comment: you can get more info about ILM at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/overview-index-lifecycle-management.html